# SQL using lookup table to create a supplier quote

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a lookup table called supplier, which has all of my suppliers information.
I also have a lookup table called materials, which has all of my materials information.
I'm creating another table called supplier_quote in which I will store 3 suppliers with at least 3 raw materials each as well as price and quantity.

the purpose of this is that the user in visual basic can call 1 supplier and get a price for each of the 3 materials, call the next supplier and input the price of the same 3 materials and again with the 3rd supplier.

I was thinking a drop down box in the form to display each suppliers name and raw material, but so far I can't seem to understand the logic behind it.

I need something like this:

```
supplier 1
raw material A.      $23
raw material B.      $25
raw material C       $30

supplier 2
raw material A.      $22
raw material B.      $21
raw material c.      $35

supplier 3
raw material A.      $23
raw material B.      $32
raw material C.      $29
```

all that information would be one record in the supplier_quote table, because it all goes in one same quote. the prices are input by the person doing the quote, so I'm guessing they get stored in this same table.

anyone please help? I appreciate it in advance. I'm using visual basic 2010 and SQL 2008.

Comment: Appears to me your data's not normalized.  A supplier can be on zero to many quotes but a quote must have have one or many suppliers.  Each quote could have one or many raw materials.  Each raw material can be on zero to many quotes. So the tables involved in my opinion are supplier, materials, quote, supplier_quote_materials.  Supplier_Quote_Materials contains SupplierID, Quote_Id and Materials ID as well as price.

Comment: so what goes inside quote? I've been struggling with this problem for two days already and can't move forward. your explanation is perfect you fully understood the concept, could you help me identify what attributes would go on the other table and which form should my GUI use as main form?

Comment: Without knowing requirements this is difficult to answer.. I've taken a shot but it is truly a SWAG (S***ty Wild A** Guess)  Really seems like you're missing a Business Analyst to ask these questions about requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Quote (just some ideas on what I may track but this is where requirements need clarification)

- ID
- Name
- Reason for quote (Why do you need this quote?)
- Requested By (who's asking for it perhaps linked back to user?)
- For Project #... (Do you track these to a specific project or RFP?)
- Due By Date (when do all the proposals from vendors need to be returned by?)
- Etc...
- Request For Proposal # (internally how do you track quote requests ?)

Supplier

- ID
- Name

Material

- ID
- Name

Supplier_Quote

- Quote_ID
- Supplier_ID
- StartDate (Date supplier pricing is good form)
- EndDate (date supplier pricing is good to  leave null if open ended.)

Supplier_Quote_Materials

- Quote_ID
- Supplier_ID
- Material_ID
- Price
- Quantity limits etc...

User Interface:

User enters "Quote Maintenance transaction"

- tabbed interface or multiple sections you decide.

Tab 1 - Quotes

- Search
- Quote Listing Results (when selected detail section is updated to reflect selection)
- Detail (Add/Delete/save buttons)

Tab 2 - Suppliers ( Disabled until a quote is selected on tab 1)

- Search
- Supplier Listing Results (when selected detail section is updated to reflect selection)
- Detail (Add/Delete/Save buttons)

Tab 3 - Materials (disabled until a supplier is selected on tab 2)

- Search
- Materials Listing (when selected detail section is updated to reflect selection)
- Detail (add/Delete/Save buttons

The relationships between quote, supplier and materials is maintained though sections/tabs. thus a user is adding suppliers to quotes, and then materials to suppliers which are related to quotes.

Comment: xQbert I'll try this one, I have an image but I cannot attach it because of reputation, but I'll try to describe better my scenario.

A customer calls and ask for a product, I call my suppliers to see which gets me the best price on the materials to manufacture that product. I want to call this document "supplier quote", on this form all I will do is save the supplier, raw material name and price on this table as Quote 1, and so on. I'm trying your method right now, I appreciate your help.

Comment: There is a customer ID, but that I can retrieve no problem, also I have an employee ID but that I can also retrieve no problem since it is just 1 person each. I track them based on a Customer_Quote so that goes with this one as well, but I have no problem there either.